# Trouble looping through an array of arrays in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops, each

I'm a junior Ruby coder. I'm currently trying to figure out what's wrong with the code I'm writing. Basically, I have an array-of-arrays and I'm trying to loop through it and puts each array as a string. But no matter what I do, nothing works unless I do it long-hand, which I really don't want to do.
To start off, here's my array:

```
array1 = [["Mittens", "is", "a", "cat"], ["Lily", "is", "a", "dog"], ["Alex", "is", "a", "turtle"]]
```

I want to put the results up so that it turns out like so:

```
Mittens is a cat
Lily is a dog
Alex is a turtle
```

I've been trying to use this or a variation of this for a few hours now:

```
array1.each do |sub_array|
  sub_array.join(" ")
  puts sub_array
end
```

But whenever I try it, it ends up looking like this:

```
Mittens
is
a
cat
Lily
is
a
dog
Alex
is
a
turtle
```

Now if I change "puts" to "print", I just get the same three arrays I got before. So without completing giving up and just hard coding three "puts" statements in my program, what am I missing here? I know it must be a very simple thing, and I would like to write a loop function that delivers this easily. Thank you for looking!

Comment: A method like `join` will not change the original object. It's basically impossible for a method to change an object from one class to another, so a String will never magically turn into an Array. The only way to change classes is to create a new variable reference through *assignment* usually with `=`. Ruby's methods can be a little tricky when it comes to what they return versus what they mutate, so always keep the documentation open and verify each call you're making. There's no shame in reading the manual.

Answer (score 3):

`Array#join` doesn't mutate sub_array, it just returns a string. You can print the results of `sub_array.join(" ")` like this:

```
array1.each do |sub_array|
  puts sub_array.join(" ")
end
```

Comment: Thank you, that was a good solution that I wasn't quite considering.

Answer (score 1):

Like seph said, the `join` method *returns* a string, but doesn't convert the array to a string (http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-join).

So, you can do this:

```
 array1.each do |sub_array|
     sub_array_string = sub_array.join(" ")
     puts sub_array_string
 end
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: You're mostly right, but the intermediate variable isn't necessary and makes this code overly verbose. The note about the function of the `join` method is important, though.

Comment: @tadman For sure. Did that to demonstrate that it was returning a string.